# lightgallery is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, lightgallery

I am using localhost xampp for practise.. I have implemented a lightgallery to show images from my images folder with js but lightgallery does not show me that images as gallaery..

here i snippet my code ....

```
$(element).lightgallery();
```

is not working... where element is class of span tag  and this class and span is created by js (`var container ="<span> <bla> <bl>image<bl/> </bla></span>"; $("#this_div_id_in_html_page_or_this_div_of_html_page").append(container);`)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesarray= [];
  imagesarray[0] = "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg";
  imagesarray[1] = "http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg";
  imagesarray[2] = "http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg";
  imagesarray[3] = "http://i765.photobucket.com/albums/xx291/just-meller/national%20geografic/Birds-national-geographic-6873734-1600-1200.jpg";
  imagesarray[4] = "http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg";
  
  var hiddenimages = "",albumcover;
  $("#appendnewcontainer").click(function (){
  /*for (var i = 0; i < imagesarray.length; i++) {
    imagepath = imagesarray[i];
    hiddenimages += "<a class='hidimage' href=" + imagepath + "><img src=" + imagepath + "/></a>"
  }*/

  var glryPostContainer = "<span class='container'>" +
                              "<span class='imagecontiner'>" +
                                 "<a class='dfed' href=" + imagesarray[1] + ">" +
                                    "<img src='" + imagesarray[1] + "' class='_34'/>" +
                                   "</a>" +
                                "</span>" +
                          "</span>";
  
  $("#fotoappendarea").append(glryPostContainer);
    });
  $(".imagecontiner").lightGallery();
});
```

```css
#fotoappendarea {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 550px;
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 450px;
      margin: 10px 0px;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.2.8/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.2.8/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<div id="appendnewcontainer"> Click me To make new album</div>
<div id="fotoappendarea"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue , even your demo is working . But as you wrote in snippet it has be

`$(".imagecontiner").lightGallery();`

& not

```
$(".imagecontiner").lightgallery();
```

Note the camelcase

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/y92rqgbz/)

Answer (score 0):

working example..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesarray = [];
  imagesarray[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/500/500";
  imagesarray[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/500/450";
  imagesarray[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/200/600";
  imagesarray[3] = "http://lorempixel.com/500/200";
  imagesarray[4] = "http://lorempixel.com/300/300";

  var hiddenimages = "";
  $("#appendnewcontainer").click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imagesarray.length; i++) {

      hiddenimages += "<a class='hidimage dfed' href=" + imagesarray[i] + "><img class='_34' src=" + imagesarray[i] + "></a>"
    }
    console.log(hiddenimages);
    var glryPostContainer = "<span class='container'>" +
      "<span class='imagecontiner'>" +
      "<a class='dfed' href=" + imagesarray[0] + ">" +
      "<img src='" + imagesarray[0] + "' class='_34'>" +
      "</a>" +
      hiddenimages +
      "</span>" +
      "</span>";

    $("#fotoappendarea").append(glryPostContainer);
  });
  $(".imagecontiner").lightGallery();
});
```

```css
#fotoappendarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 550px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: 450px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.hidimage {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.2.8/css/lightgallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.2.8/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>

<div id="appendnewcontainer">Click me To make new album</div>
<div id="fotoappendarea"></div>
```